# Django set form field after POST request

Tags: django

I'm using class-based views (FormView) and I would like to keep a search keyword after form is submitted (POST request). I tried this in `form_valid` method:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        self.initial['search'] = form.data['search']
        ...
```

but this will show it for all users. This is quite common solution on many web search forms (not to mention Google search) so I wonder how this can be done in Django.

**Update: Mon 19 Jun 13:18:42 UTC 2017**

Based on some answers below I'll have to rephrase my question.

I have a simple form with a few input fields, after a form is submitted it will query other sites to get the results based on a search term. I would like to store some results into database, mainly to produce stats, re-display the form with selected fields and show results.

Currently data resides on a class object and it's passed from POST to GET. This is not a good solution for obvious security reasons:

```
class SearchView(FormView):
    ...
    data = dict()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ....
        self.data['results'] = results

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['data'] = self.data.pop('results', None)
        return context
```

**Question:**

What would be the best way to display form (with selected fields) and results on the same page, preferably without sessions or storing them in database between POST and GET.

Points that I already considered:

1. Don't redirect the user (render the template with the current context right away, while we still have the response object) - *I don't like the fact that page refresh will re-submit the form.*
2. Save the response into some key-value store like Redis and redirect the user to something like results/{result_id}, where we can retrieve the response from database to pre-fill the form with data and show the results - *this sounds reasonable but I'll have to add another component just to pass the results from POST to GET.*
3. Use GET for this type of form - *my understanding was that we should use POST for data modification*

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev please se my update: `Update: Mon 19 Jun 13:18:42 UTC 2017`

Comment: Usually a search does not modify data.  I think you are likely addressing this conceptually wrong.  I have done a hybrid view (but not class based) that is half-GET and half-POST.  You first do a search to find the dataset you want to change, then another page loads that allows you to modify the records returned by the search but preserves your GET search. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: I know you're searching for a Django solution, but just as a thought: This sounds like something you could more easily solve on the client side by doing the requests to other sites you mention via AJAX and manage the results directly on the frontend. Then you'll only work with the final submission.

Answer (score 5):

Google and other similar searches use `GET` params to pass query string

**Exmaple**:

1. Google `test`
2. Result url will be `https://www.google.ru/?q=test`

So basically you need to use same approach and pass you search string as `GET` param.

Here is general Idea

```
class SearchView(View):
    success_url = reverse('result-view')

    def get_success_url(self):
        success_url = super().get_success_url()
        return '{0}?search={1}'.format(success_url, self.form.cleaned_data['search'])
    ...

class ResultView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        search_string = request.GET.get('search', '')
```

Comment: OK, but I'll store some results in database and it's recommended to use POST in that case.

Comment: @HTF I am not suggesting to change the way you handle your view. The way `POST` in django generic views works, is that after successful submit it does redirect to `success_url`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) All I am suggesting is to pass this search string as `GET` parameters to this success view.

Comment: did this work for you because  in my case, class instance has no attribute 'form?

Comment: @HTF Example is pseudo code, it shouldn't work. I've written it just to give you general idea. If you will provide your full `SearchView` I will use it for my suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

From your update: I think this is the process you are looking for:

1. user fills the form with empty search term
2. user POST the form with search term
3. you query other sites in this POST request, and display your form again with term
4. user is presented with the pre-filled form and results (no redirection or you would lose context)

You basically need to prevent the redirection when form is valid:

```
class SearchPageView(FormView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # do your things (3) here
        context = self.get_context_data(form=form)
        context['results'] = ['lorem', 'ipsum']
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: What if I would like to also store some search results in database? I guess POST is recommended in that case?

Comment: It depends on how much you want to process/store, if you just want to do some stats on search terms, it's all right

Comment: Modified answer from your Update

Comment: Thanks, what would be the proper way to pass results to context in this case?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't make it clear exactly how long you want to keep the keyword stored.

If it's just that response, as long as you're rendering the form correctly the keyword will still be there:

```
>>> from django import forms
>>> class MyForm(forms.Form):
...     search = forms.CharField()
...
>>> f = MyForm(data={'search': 'KEYWORD'})
>>> print(f['search'])
<input id="id_search" name="search" type="text" value="KEYWORD" />
```

If you want to keep the keyword across requests but just for that user, use the [sessions framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.request.session['search'] = form.data['search']
    ...

def get_form(self, form_class):
    form = super(self, YourView).get_form(form_class)
    form.initial['search'] = self.request.session.get('search', '')
    return form
```

Comment: I just want to keep the search phrase after form is submitted, so user can re-submit form with the same or modified keyword but if site is opened on a new tab, form should be empty. Session is not efficient, it will require a database hit on each search just to store a search string. If I try `form.data['search'] = 'TEST'` in `get_form` Django throws `This QueryDict instance is immutable`. [This](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) is an example what I want, you can see URL after form is submitted but only for current user and not on another tab.

Comment: Sessions don't have to use the database, but as you've clarified, you didn't need this anyway. All you needed was built in to Django forms already. Glad you got it worked out :)

Answer (score 2):

**views.py**

```
class SearchView(FormView):
    template_name = 'apps/frontend/search_view.j2'

    def get_form_class(self):
        class _Form(forms.Form):
            search = forms.CharField(label='search')

        return _Form


    def form_valid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

**html**

```
<h1>current:{{ form.search.value()|default('') }} - jinja2 format</h1>

<form action="." method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation that I believe satisfies all your requirements.  Especially, we can reprompt the user's input by having `form_valid()` return `super(SearchView, self).get(self.request)`.  This way, the Django server behaves as processing a normal POST operation from the user's perspective.

**views.py**

```
class SearchView(FormView):
    template_name = 'yourapp/search.html'
    form_class = SearchForm
    results = ''  # for {{ view.results }}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.results = form.get_results()
        return super(SearchView, self).get(self.request)
```

**forms.py**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    input = forms.CharField()

    def get_results(self):
        input_data = self.cleaned_data['input']
        results = "results for %s" % input_data  # <-- modify this process as you need
        # ... (your operations for input_data and results here)
        return results
```

**yourapp/search.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<p>{{ view.results }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use GET for this type of form - my understanding was that we should
>   use POST for data modification

Use GET only to populate `form.initial` values, you can still submit the form as POST.

```
# for python3 
# from urllib.parse import urlencode 
from urllib import urlencode

class SearchView(FormView):
    def get_initial(self):
        return {'search': self.request.GET.get('search')}

    def form_valid(self, form):
        search = self.request.POST.get('search')
        url = self.get_success_url() + '?' + urlencode({'search': search})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: Your version overwrites any other initial data in the form.  See my answer for a way to preserve it.

Comment: Ye I know that, but since the OP did not specify how its Form looks like, I don't think there is anything to overwrite. However more important is to understand the principle, the implementation can be justified.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a bit iffy on what you want to do (searches are usually done via GET and then Django exhibits the desired behavior).  But I think you should be able to do this by overwriting `get_initial():` and pulling the value(s) out of `self.request.POST`.

If all you want to do it keep the submitted value in the initialization of the next value, that's the best approach.

I.e. something like this inside your View class for Python 3 (your super call needs to be a bit different in Python 2):

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super().get_initial()

    initial['search'] = self.request.POST.get('search', '')

    return initial
```